# Infinispan with MongoDB error: Unable to start cache loaders

Tags: mongodb, infinispan

I'm writing a web service layer using Resteasy and I tried to configure infinispan as a server side response cache, as described here: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#server_cache

Because this layer is stateless and might be deployed on a multitude of nodes on heroku, I wanted to use a mongodb cache loader to store the cache data. This way, the cache would be synched between all nodes.

However, when starting my server in my local machine, I get the following error:

org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start cache loaders (full stack trace at the end of this message)

Here's my declared dependencies:

```
compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.1.Final'
compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client:3.0.1.Final'
compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-spring:3.0.1.Final'
compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-cache-core:3.0.1.Final'
compile 'org.infinispan:infinispan-cachestore-mongodb:5.3.0.Final'
```

*(It's strange that the org.infinispan:infinispan-cachestore-mongodb:5.3.0.Final jar includes almost all the classes also present in org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-cache-core:3.0.1.Final. I wonder if that's what is causing the problem. I played a lot with the dependency graph trying to exclude the duplicates to a point where I built my own mongo cache loader jar with only the pertinent classes, but doing that or removing the core jar and leaving only the mongo cache loader jar thrown an exception like Unexpected element '{urn:infinispan:config:5.3}infinispan'
)*

I also configured infinispan.xml following the documentation on the site: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Cache+Loaders+and+Stores#CacheLoadersandStores-MongoDBcacheloader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.3
                              http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.3.xsd
                              urn:infinispan:config:mongodb:5.3
                              https://raw.github.com/infinispan/infinispan/5.3.x/cachestore/mongodb/src/main/resources/schema/mongodb-cachestore-config-5.3.xsd"
 xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.3">

     <namedCache name="nf-demo">
          <eviction strategy="LIRS" maxEntries="10" />
               <loaders>
                    <mongodbStore xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:mongodb:5.3">
                         <connection host="localhost" port="27017" timeout="2000"
                              acknowledgment="0" />
                         <storage database="infinispan_test_database" collection="infispan_cachestore" />
                    </mongodbStore>
               </loaders>
     </namedCache>
</infinispan>
```

I'm not sure if it's a version conflict which is causing the issue or if it is a bug on the mongodb cache laoder. I'm also not sure if there's an additional step I need to perform to register the mongo db loader within infospan config. On another thread, someone had the same error when creating a custom loader because he didn't implement the CacheLoaderConfig.getCacheLoaderClassName(). I fussed around the mongo db loader source code in github but couldn't find any reference to this method. Here's the thread for reference: https://community.jboss.org/thread/218305

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Full Stacktrace:

```
Failed startup of context org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext@6823bf90{/avivoca,/Users/daniel.freitas/dev/projects/mtl-lp-notification-layer/src/main/webapp}
org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start() on object of type CacheLoaderManagerImpl
          at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:207)
          at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:889)
          at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:658)
          at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:647)
          at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:550)
          at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:221)
          at org.infinispan.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:691)
          at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:685)
          at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:648)
          at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:544)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.cache.server.ServerCacheFeature.getXmlCache(ServerCacheFeature.java:88)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.cache.server.ServerCacheFeature.getCache(ServerCacheFeature.java:61)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.cache.server.ServerCacheFeature.configure(ServerCacheFeature.java:36)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1673)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1310)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.registerProvider(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:1232)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registerProvider(ResteasyDeployment.java:531)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:346)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:241)
          at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1272)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext.doStart(JettyPluginWebAppContext.java:112)
          at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
          at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
          at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
          at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
          at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:111)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJettyInternal(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:247)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJetty(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:198)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.start(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:169)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
          at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
          at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
          at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
          at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
          at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.JettyRun_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
          at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
          at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
          at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
          at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
          at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
          at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
          at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
          at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
          at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
          at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
          at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
          at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
          at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
          at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
          at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
          at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
          at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
          at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
          at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
          at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
          at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
          at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
          at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
          at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
          at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
          at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
          at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start cache loaders
          at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:163)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
          at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
          ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load null class!
          at org.infinispan.util.Util.getInstance(Util.java:224)
          at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.createCacheLoader(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:346)
          at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.createCacheLoader(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:336)
          at org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl.start(CacheLoaderManagerImpl.java:149)
          ... 135 more
```

**UPDATE**

I step traced the source code for Infinispan and I narrowed down the error to this method on class org.infinispan.loaders.CacheLoaderManagerImpl. The cfg instance is of type org.infinispan.loaders.mongodb.MongoDBCacheStoreConfig, which interestingly I can't find on any library in Eclipse's classpath. So I assume this class is created at runtime? The NPE error is reported because cfg.getCacheLoaderClassName() returns null on the very 1st line.

```
CacheLoader createCacheLoader(CacheLoaderConfig cfg, AdvancedCache<Object, Object> cache) throws Exception {
  CacheLoader tmpLoader = (CacheLoader) Util.getInstance(cfg.getCacheLoaderClassName(), cache.getClassLoader());

  if (tmpLoader != null) {
     if (cfg instanceof CacheStoreConfig) {
        CacheStore tmpStore = (CacheStore) tmpLoader;
        // async?
        CacheStoreConfig cfg2 = (CacheStoreConfig) cfg;
        if (cfg2.getAsyncStoreConfig().isEnabled()) {
           tmpStore = createAsyncStore(tmpStore, cfg2);
           tmpLoader = tmpStore;
        }

        // read only?
        if (cfg2.isIgnoreModifications()) {
           tmpStore = new ReadOnlyStore(tmpStore);
           tmpLoader = tmpStore;
        }

        // singleton?
        SingletonStoreConfig ssc = cfg2.getSingletonStoreConfig();
        if (ssc != null && ssc.isSingletonStoreEnabled()) {
           tmpStore = new SingletonStore(tmpStore, cache, ssc);
           tmpLoader = tmpStore;
        }
     }

     // load props
     tmpLoader.init(cfg, cache, m);
  }
  return tmpLoader;
```

}

Comment: Hmmmm, weird. All looks good at first glance. Either you trace debug through the code with an IDE to see why it's trying to load a null class, or you provide a test zip or similar where we can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: Thanks Galder. I shall have some time soon to look into it. I will upload the zip somewhere and in the meantime I will step debug through the code.

Comment: I updated my question with more info.

Comment: The MongoDBCacheStoreConfig class is in infinispan-cachestore-mongodb-5.3.0.Final.jar (https://gist.github.com/galderz/475d038cc8889bdaea91). What might be happening is that the constructor with parameters is used (http://goo.gl/OYQcWu) instead of the empty one, and the one that receives parameters does not set the cache loader class name. It's interesting that it's not caught by the testsuite. Can you check if this is true? And maybe provide a stacktrace leading to that call if this constructor is getting called?

Comment: Thanks Galder for the heads up. Unfortunately I don't have much free time these days to test it out. However, I believe this is pointing in the right direction so hopefully others (or eventually myself if I ever get back to this project) can make it work.